# how to run query Through 2 database - sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have 2 database

database 1: AA  with table MEN

database 2: BB  with table MEN

i need to run query that look for the same Fname and Lname

that has in AA.MEN and BB.MEN

how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Fname, Lname FROM AA..MEN
INTERSECT
SELECT Fname, Lname FROM BB..MEN
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT *
FROM AA..MEN
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM BB..MEN
    WHERE BB..MEN.Fname = AA..MEN.Fname
        AND BB..MEN.Lname = AA..MEN.Lname
)
```